# Combine two elastic queries into 1. How?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have two queries which fetched results when performed a GET operation. 
The 1st query is -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "database-status.meta.current-time": {
              "lte": "now-91d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "database-status.meta.current-time",
        "interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "database-status.name.keyword",
            "size": 500,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "database-status.status-properties.rate-properties.cache-properties.compressed-tree-cache-hit-rate.value",
                "script": "_value/60"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the 2nd query is -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "database-status.meta.current-time": {
              "lte": "now-91d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "database-status.meta.current-time",
        "interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "database-status.name.keyword",
            "size": 500,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "database-status.status-properties.rate-properties.cache-properties.compressed-tree-cache-miss-rate.value",
                "script": "_value/60"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I combine two queries into 1 query and get both the results in the same result sets? Based on this I'll try to replicate the method with other queries and even try to combine 3 or more queries into 1.

Comment: If the second query doesn't depend on the result of the first one, I'd go with [multi-search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to do that:

1. using [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) (msearch) will allow you to run one request to ES containing both queries. The response of the msearch will contain both queries responses separately, and you can then choose how to combine the answers.
2. combine the queries in a single bool:

so lets say you have:
Q1->bool->must->inner-q-1
and Q2->bool->must->inner-q-2

then you can combine them with should:
Q3->bool->should->[inner-q-1, inner-q-2], with [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) equals 1 (very important!)

Comment: For option 2, you might also want to use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) (i.e. give a name to each inner query) in order to know which result matches which query

Comment: @Val The query is small.. Most of the part is aggregation. Can we combine aggregations ?

Comment: Hi bosari :) the aggregations can get combined as well. In two ways: 1. Just have them one after the other, not nested, like: "aggs":{ "2": {...the aggs from the first query..}, "the_second_q_2" :{... The aggs from the second query...}} OR 2. As the aggs are almost identical, you can do a similar combination on the third level aggs (the one named "1" in your example). Then you will get the answers of both aggs

Comment: And another, third option, is to use filter aggregation, which let's you narrow down the aggs results with a query/filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

I made use of nested aggregation. 
Here is the combined code -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "server-status.meta.current-time": {
              "lte": "now-91d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "time-interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "server-status.meta.current-time",
        "interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "http-server": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "server-status.type.keyword",
            "include": "http-server",
            "size": 500,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "server-status.status-properties.expanded-tree-cache-hit-rate.value",
                "script": "_value/60"
              }
            },
            "2": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "server-status.status-properties.expanded-tree-cache-miss-rate.value",
                "script": "_value/60"
              }
            },
            "3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "server-status.name.keyword",
                "size": 500,
                "order": {
                  "1": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "1": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "server-status.status-properties.expanded-tree-cache-hit-rate.value",
                    "script": "_value/60"
                  }
                },
                "2": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "server-status.status-properties.expanded-tree-cache-miss-rate.value",
                    "script": "_value/60"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```